# How can I calculate elements in one vector?

Tags: vhdl

I'm new at VHDL code, and I'm trying to figure out, how is the easiest way to calculate elements in **STD_LOGIC_VECTOR**.

so how my ports look like:

```
Port ( D : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (width-1 downto 0);  -- data input
           parity : out STD_LOGIC                       -- parity bit
    );
```

so I want to do something like this (code in c)

```
int helper = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
   if (D[i] == 1) {
       helper++;
   }
}
if (helper % 2 == 0) {
    parity = 1;
}
```

if im not enought clear sorry for that, i can probably answer your question, if there will be.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this in VHDL is with `xor_reduce` from `ieee.std_logic_misc`. Addition modulo 2 is exactly the same as XOR, and `xor_reduce` XORs all of the inputs together, giving you the addition modulo 2 of your input bits. This would look like:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_misc.xor_reduce;

entity PARITY_GEN is
    generic (width : integer := 8);
    port( D: in std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
        parity: out std_logic
    );
end PARITY_GEN;

architecture bhv of PARITY_GEN is
begin
    process(D)
    begin
        parity <= xor_reduce(D);
    end process;
end bhv;
```

If you don't want to include `xor_reduce`, you could do the same just using `xor`:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity PARITY_GEN is
    generic (width : integer := 8);
    port( D: in std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
        parity: out std_logic
    );
end PARITY_GEN;

architecture bhv of PARITY_GEN is
begin
    process(D)
        variable temp:std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
    begin
        temp(0) := D(0);
        loop:for i in 1 to width-1 generate
            temp(i) := temp(i-1) xor D(i);
        end generate;
        parity <= temp(width-1);
    end process;
end bhv;
```

Comment: There's also the -2008 unary xor  (does the same thing as XOR_REDUCE) in IEEE package std_logic_1164. The conditional assignment statement `parity <= '0' when xor d else '1';` would return odd parity in -2008 counting on an implicit conditional operator (in a condition). Reversing the '1' and '0' literals would give you even parity.